# typescript, declare that 2 props must have tha same value

Tags: typescript

I want to declare that `x` must have the same value as `y` in the same object.

The case is that I'm creating the types for an third-party webhook that has some relics of older versions, where there are 2 variables that means the same thing and I want to make sure I follow that on the tests example webhooks.

example of what i want to do:

```js
interface test {
  x: "1" | "2";
  y: valueof this["x"];
}

const x: test = {
  x: "1",
  y: "2" // throw error here that says y must be equal to "1"
}
```